# play the next audio in applet

Tags: java, android

Please could someone help me!! I need to play automatically the next sound in an applet.

I am planning on creating an mp3 player.

Thank you for your help

public class Darija extends JApplet {

```
JButton Button = new JButton("Speak");
AudioClip sound1;
AudioClip sound2;


public void init()
{  
    setLayout(null);       
   Button.addActionListener(new Actions());
    sound1 = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "01.wav");
    sound2 = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "02.wav");

  Button.setBounds(200, 72, 94, 40);

    add(Button);

}

public class Actions implements ActionListener 
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
  {
      if(ev.getSource() == Button)
      {

          sound1.play();

      }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: What does this have to do with jsp or C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use mediaplayer for this purpose..
put your media clips in res/raw folder and then on button click play sounds like this

```
MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound1);  
MediaPlayer mp2=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound2);         

mp1.prepare();
mp2.prepare();   
mp1.start();
mp1.setNextMediaPlayer(mp2);
```